# Find and replace changing date format in notepad++ using regular expressions

Tags: regex, string, date, notepad++

I need to change date format of many values in a SQL file.

There are date values which are in the 'DD-MON-RR' format but I need them to be in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

In the file I have dates from 21th century and 20th century:

```
to_date('01-Nov-20','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('28-Dec-99','DD-MON-RR')
```

I'm searching for a regex to find and replace those values.

This was my first try, works even with the 20th century years:

```
FIND: 
(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(([0-4])\d|[5-9]\d)

REPLACE: 
(?{4}20:19)\3-\2-\1
```

This one helps to reorder the position of elements but I have to replace all the months with related numbers.

Now I'm searching for something to find and replace month names in the same regex:

```
FIND: 
(\d{2})-((Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))-(([0-4])\d|[5-9]\d)
```

Now I'm having trouble trying to write the replace expression, someone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define as many month (month abbreviations) instead of `(\w{3})` and use a bit more conditions in the conditional replacement pattern.

You can use

*Find What*: `(\d{2})-(?:(Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))-(([0-4])\d|[5-9]\d)`
*Replace With*: `(?{15}20:19)$14-(?{13}12:?{12}11:?{11}10:?{10}09:?{9}08:?{8}07:?{7}06:?{6}05:?{5}04:?{4}03:?{3}02:?{2}01)-$1`

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

So, `(\w{3})` is replaced with `(?:(Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))`, a non-capturing group with 12 capturing groups. You may edit it, say, to also support `Sept`, add `t?` after `Sep`, or add `e?` after `Jun` to also support `June`.

The replacement pattern is adjusted to account for the newly introduced 12 capturing groups.

Comment: Why not a single capturing group such as `(Jan|Feb|Mar|…)`?

Comment: @knittl Because each month group should be separately tested for a match, else, you the conditional replacement pattern can't be used.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I've never used conditional replaces in NP++